# Refused to display in an frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

FOllowing the video and sample code from          https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-js to upload any file from local system to google drve i was stuck with an error which states

"**Refused to display** 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=%3CAIzaSyDa2kGIMQCLdfzk…%2Flocalhost&response_type=token&state=513052220%7C0.1330524626&authuser=0' **in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'**."

I registered for a new client ID and also changes in the code with new clien ID
Also disabled the chrome security using "**chrome.exe --user-data-dir="c:/temp/chromedev" --disable-web-security**" in run command.

Comment: Can anyone help me in resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not related to disabling security in chrome browser.
I believe there might me some issues with my XAMPP Windows local host.Deploying the same application in node.js server or hosting Dropbox/Google Drive as a web app also works fine.

Comment: this is not answer. you are trolling.

Comment: If you know the answer don't use the word BELIEVE.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the below issue while loading the PDF document into iframe from google drive.

**Problem:**
Refused to display 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ipnylkWoSx4NS0GtmsQVFUq7ms339DAW/view' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

**Reason:**
As per my analysis, I faced this issue due to the URL is not considering as embedded to allow loading from other websites.

**Solution:**
I did even tried with the solution of adding ?embedded=true to the URL but still no luck. Then I got one solution from https://support.google.com/drive/thread/34363118?hl=en and replaced the view with preview in my URL and problem solved.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ipnylkWoSx4NS0GtmsQVFUq7ms339DAW/preview

Answer (score 1):

The browswer sequrity is nonsense since Google Realtime API is intended to work with default security.

I received this error when supplied `clientId = 'garbage'`. Indeed, your `client_id=<AIzaSyDa2kGIMQCLdfzk` looks like garbage. Correct client_id shoud look like '1088706429537-4oqhqr7o826ditbok23sll1rund1jim1.apps.googleusercontent.com'

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still relevant, i got the same error loading a google docs in an iframe. After stripping the page of everything i had, removing the doctype solved my issue.
After this i found out there was a parameter ?embedded=true which allowed me to load it in a fancybox, which looks nicer anyway. Hope it helps any1, sorry if it's not relevant for you.