# Error running sample code to upload a file to google drive

Tags: google-drive-api

Following the tutorial from https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-js to upload any sample document from local system to goolge drive but was stucj with following error which states 
"Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=%3CAIzaSyDa2kGIMQCLdfzk…%2Flocalhost&response_type=token&state=513052220%7C0.1330524626&authuser=0' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN"
I changed the client Id also , but the error remains the same, is it something to deal with the Google API BUG ?

Comment: How are your running the html page (from file, webserver? in an iframe?) and did you set the 'Authorized JavaScript origins' correctly when creating the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might me some issues with my XAMPP Windows local host.Deploying the same application in node.js server or hosting Dropbox/Google Drive as a webapp also works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error when supplied clientId = 'garbage'. Indeed, your `client_id=<AIzaSyDa2kGIMQCLdfzk` looks like garbage. Correct client_id shoud look like '1088706429537-4oqhqr7o826ditbok23sll1rund1jim1.apps.googleusercontent.com'

You also [had another answer on 3rd May](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449486).