# Google Drive file upload using JavaScript API throwing Error of X-Frame-Options

Tags: javascript, api, file-upload, google-drive-api

I'm using Google Drive API for uploading an file to google drive using javascript sdk, I'm following the tutorial from the [official page](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-js) but while running the Application I'm getting an Error in console which says

```
 Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=27050131367-74qcgvobdsc…host%3A3000&response_type=token&state=1889213326%7C0.2632152967&authuser=0' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

I tried to search on Internet and came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449486/refused-to-display-in-an-frame-because-it-set-x-frame-options-to-sameorigin) but the solution did not worked out for me I'm using the same code which is there on the google drive documentation page.

I've tried running the Application in my local wamp, local node js and also deployed it on two live server one is the php server [here](http://www.webashlar.com/Demos/imguruplod/googleD.html) and one on google App engine [here](http://demoapp-test.appspot.com/index.html) but still in chrome I'm getting the same Error.

Could someone please help me in this ?..

Answer (score 0):

Is something not working? I see similar errors using the JS client library and everything works fine, I think it's just a side effect of how the client itself is put together.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a JavaScript origin in the Google Developer Console for the Client ID you are using, and it must match the server that the page is hosted on. This isn't listed clearly in the instructions, but I've opened a bug to have that fixed.