# Android App + Cordova + HTML5 + Google Drive Api

Tags: android, html, cordova, google-drive-api

I developed a html5 page to list google drive files and test with PhoneGap server. All works fine, because I created a Oauth2 with http://localhost:3000 configured.

When I tried to test a APK file, with SHA1 (also configured on Oauth2 in google drive console), I received the error:

`Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=<KEY>' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'. I understand that this error is because the Oauth2 doesn't expect the origin. But the Origin is not http, if file know... (file:///android_asset/www/index.html). The GoogleAPI Console doesn't accept 'file' protocol... just 'http'.`

How can I solve this?

Comment: you can check my answer on a similar SO [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35746756/how-implement-google-drive-in-ionic-app/42412306#42412306)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to solution given in this SO post - [Refused to display in an frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449486/refused-to-display-in-an-frame-because-it-set-x-frame-options-to-sameorigin), regarding error encountered:

> This is not related to disabling security in chrome browser. I believe there might me some issues with my XAMPP Windows local host.Deploying the same application in node.js server or hosting Dropbox/Google Drive as a web app also works fine.

Additionally, to make a request, as discussed in step #2 from the [**basic steps**](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#basicsteps) in using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs, obtain an access token from the Google Authorization Server. Ways to make a request are as follows:

- a JavaScript application might request an access token using a browser redirect to Google
- an **application installed on a device that has no browser uses web service requests.**

Sample scenarios which you can use can be found in the documentation.